# Customizing marker lists in hvplot

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

I have a dataset like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),columns=['A','B'])
df['group'] = np.random.choice(4,size=10)
df['category'] = np.random.choice(['CC','DD'],size=10)
df['sizes'] = np.random.randint(10,50,size=10)
```

and I want a scatter plot of A vs B with the markers colored by the 'group' column, and with markers' type based on the 'category' column, marker size based on the 'sizes' column.

The following...

```
scatter = df.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='B',color='group',padding=0.1,cmap='Set1',size='sizes')
scatter
```

...gets me the correct coloring, and while I get a "Cannot declare mapping for 'size' option" (any idea why?), I actually get the correct marker sizing.

However, I can't seem to get marker types based on 'category' column.

I have tried...

```
markers=['x' if zone=='DD' else 'o' for zone in df['category']]
scatter = df.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='B',color='group',padding=0.1,cmap='Set1',size='sizes',marker=markers)
scatter
```

... but it convert ALL points to crosses(x) and none to circles(o).

I also tried adding a column:

```
df['markers'] = np.random.choice(['x','o'],size=10)
```

and then...

```
scatter = df.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='B',color='group',padding=0.1,cmap='Set1',size='sizes',marker='markers')
scatter
```

... but this throws an error and doesn't work at all.

What is the right way to customize markers by variable using hvplot?

Appreciate your suggestions.

---

**EDIT 1:**
Now I've also tried to use holoviews.dim, 1. with holoviews:

```
hvd = hv.Dataset(df,['A'],['B','markers'])
markers_custom = hv.dim('markers').apply(hvd)

hvd.to.scatter().opts(marker=marker)
```

and then 2. again with hvplot:

```
scatter = df.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='B',marker=markers_custom)
```

I get:

> TypeError [Call holoviews.ipython.show_traceback() for details]
>   unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

...in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried `dim()` as at http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Style_Mapping.html?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it. Updated my efforts on the post above. I'm guessing i'm doing it wrong cause i couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above works but we very much recommend not transforming your actual data unless you really need to which is why we introduced so called `dim` expressions, which you can read about [here](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Style_Mapping.html). These let you express complex transform without having to touch your data, e.g. in your example you could do:

```
import holoviews as hv

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),columns=['A','B'])
df['group'] = np.random.choice(4,size=10)
df['category'] = np.random.choice(['CC','DD'],size=10)
df['sizes'] = np.random.randint(10,50,size=10)
marker = hv.dim("category").categorize({'DD': 'x'}, default='circle')

df.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='B', color="group", size="sizes", marker=marker)
```

The transform here basically takes the category column and transforms it by mapping all 'DD' values to 'x' and all other values to 'circle'.

Comment: Nice. Thank you! It works and does feel more powerful and convenient.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me with a custom column:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, holoviews as hv, hvplot.pandas
hv.extension("bokeh")
np.random.seed(3)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),columns=['A','B'])
df['group'] = np.random.choice(4,size=10)
df['category'] = np.random.choice(['CC','DD'],size=10)
df['sizes'] = np.random.randint(10,50,size=10)
df['marker'] = df.category.replace("DD","x").replace("CC","circle")

df.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='B', color="group", size="sizes", marker="marker")
```

[image: screenshot of plot]

Comment: Where it's supported, hv.dim() allows you to avoid having to create a custom column, but hv.dim doesn't support all possible expressions, and I wasn't able to think of a way to express a lookup table like you want using it.

Comment: What kinds of markers does hvplot take? This doesn't seem to be it: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/markers.html

Comment: I think the list is at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/markers.html .